# getting a specific image from a website link with beautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get some specific image on a website using beautiful soup :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import random

url=urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.arandomlink.com")   

content = url.read()            #We read it
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)   #We create a BeautifulSoup object
#WE OBTAIN THE URL OF THE IMAGES RELATED TO THE ITEM
images = soup.findAll("img", {'class': "arandonclass"})
print(images['src'])
```

The problem is that it doesn't work, it can't find any image even if I verified that there is images with that class.
What did I do wrong?
I'm using python 3 and BS4

Comment: give the real url which you're trying to parse, please. And real `class` value

Answer (score 0):

> [Beautiful Soup Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all)
>
> Searching by CSS class
>
> It’s very useful to search for a tag that has a certain CSS class, but the name of the CSS attribute, “class”, is a reserved word in Python. Using class as a keyword argument will give you a syntax error. As of Beautiful Soup 4.1.2, you can search by CSS class using the keyword argument class_:

```
soup.find_all("a", class_="sister")
```